# sp_nonblocking_write does sends the first byte only, whereas sp_blocking_write is working properly [under Windows]

Tags: serial-port

Under Windows XP SP3, I have tried to use sp_nonblocking_write function to send AT command to a phone connected through usb, this function always returns 1 (sends only the first byte), whereas sp_blocking_write function works without problems.

What could be the problem ?

Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: the answer is in this post:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821881/asynchronous-writefile-works-only-on-step-by-step-debugging-this-drives-me-insa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821881/asynchronous-writefile-works-only-on-step-by-step-debugging-this-drives-me-insa) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a bug. I have fixed it.